# Apache Cordova Error When Add Platforms

Tags: apache, cordova

im new in apache cordova, i try make a project with cordova, in the begining it works, but when i add some platform it giving error.

> Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

this the screen shoot
http://i39.tinypic.com/29vyla0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path."

You need to install and configure ant if you want to add Android platform :
http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Here is a guide for Android platform :
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide